# Button was enabled only for two textfields in cells both had entered text in there

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem

I have two `UITextfield` in two `cells` in one `section` in a `grouped UITableView` which called `emailField` and `passwordField`, they had set `tag` as 0 and 1. And I have a `UIBarButtonItem` called `loginButton` in the right edge of the `navigationBar`. I want the button was disabled when this view entered the screen, and want the button was enabled when both `textFields` had entered text in there, otherwise the button is disabled.

This is the code for created the button.

```
_loginButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                   target:self
                                                   action:@selector(logging)];

    _loginButton.enabled = NO;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = _loginButton;
```

And in the `UITextField` `textFieldDidBegingEditing:` method, i tried to implement this function. but it's dosen't work or worked incorrectly, it's very weird. Note:The `textFields` added as `cell`'s `subview` instead of `cell` `contentView's` `subview`.

```
#pragma mark - UITextfield Delegate

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.emailField)
    {
        UITableViewCell *currentCell = (UITableViewCell *)textField.superview;
        NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:currentCell];
        NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentIndexPath.row+1 inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *nextCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];
        self.passwordField = (UITextField *)[nextCell viewWithTag:1];
        if ([(UITextField *)[currentCell viewWithTag:0] text].length != 0 && [(UITextField *)[nextCell viewWithTag:1] text].length != 0)
        {
            self.loginButton.enabled = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            self.loginButton.enabled = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to implement this function in button selector method, but it's doesn't work at all.

```
- (IBAction)logging
{
    if (self.emailField.text.length > 0 && self.passwordField.text.length > 0)
    {
        self.loginButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.loginButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? set breakpoints and see if you get the right text field.

Comment: Did your code reach the  self.loginButton.enabled = YES statements ?

Comment: You have to be very careful using viewWithTag:0 as 0 is the default value of the view's tag. Any view that doesn't have a tag set specifically will return 0. This may not be the behaviour you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the textfields delegate property as self?
there are a few other things troubling about this code, but i'd check that first

Comment: You might want to add this as a comment on the question instead of an answer. Seems like a better fit.

Comment: Thanks, i set the delegate when textfield created.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose erian has not enough reputation for commenting questions

Comment: yup that's why i didn't add it as a comment